# rails - Find objects with duplicate attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I have an array of object `Foo` how can I find and return the objects with duplicate values for specific attributes? For instance, I want to return objects that have duplicate values for both `Foo.x` and `Foo.y`

I am using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9

I am looking for something like:

```
one = Foo.create!(:x => 1, :y => 2, :z => 3)
two = Foo.create!(:x => 1, :y => 2, :z => 6)
three = Foo.create!(:x => 4, :y => 2, :z => 3)

arr = [one, two, three]

arr.return_duplicates_for_columns(Foo.x, Foo.y) = [one, two]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean all objects where `foo.x == foo.y`?

Comment: @katafrakt let me clarify, return the objects where more objects share the values for foo.x and foo.y I'll edit the question with an example.

Comment: should it take always 2 arguments (attributes), or it should be any number of attributes?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I just need two in my case

Comment: @johnmitsch any progress with the question?

Comment: @HunterStevens yes the comment on the second answer was able to help me, let me mark that as correct

Comment: Great to hear. Why did you decide to create your own method, instead of what I suggested, which uses ActiveRecord's DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I like this solution or how well it would work for you, but it should work.

```
foos = Foo.some_ar_query_that_returns_some_foos
grouped_foos = foo.group_by {|f| [f.x, f.y]}
```

grouped_foos will now be a hash. The keys will be an array of x and y values. The values will be an array of Foo instances with the same values.  Any element of the hash where the size of the value is more than one has duplicates.

Comment: So basically to get an array of those you need to `arr.group_by{|i| [i.x, i.y]}.select{|k,v| v.length > 1}.values.flatten`

Comment: Very slick @katafrakt.  Philip you may want to edit your original answer to include this.

Comment: Not sure that would give you what you want though as now you'd have a flat array of Foos.  You wouldn't know which belong to which though.  All depends on OP's use case though I suppose.

Comment: @katafrakt awesome, many thanks, looks like that will work in my case. I am just wondering if it will take into account if values are nil? As in, if i.x is nil for two objects, would that be considered duplicates? In my particular case, I wouldn't want it to.

Comment: @johnmitsch Yes, nils would get combined. You could fix that be ensuring the original collection didn't have any Foos with a nil x or y.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom what if one had to exclude nils? add an if statement to the .select?

Comment: @johnmitsch Can you elaborate what you want or do not want with `nil` attributes?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest solution would be to use the `where` method from ActiveRecord. Using `Foo.where()` returns an array of objects, where each object matches *all* conditions provided.

For your question, I would write something similar to the following examples:

```
similar_attributes = Foo.where(x: 1, y: 2)
# => similar_attributes = [#<Foo:0x000>, #<Foo:0x001>]
# Arbitrary Foo object labels

similar_attributes.include?(one)
# => true

similar_attributes.include?(two)
# => true

similar_attributes.include?(three)
# => false

Foo.where(x: 1, y: 2).include?(one)
# => true
```